# Perform an action on all the member of JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a js object like

```
Object {id: 1, name: "Grain", Price: 26.0, DM: 2.0}
```

I want to divide all the `float values` with `2` . Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can access the Price and DM by using like objecName.Price/2 and same for DM.. can you tell me in detail if i am missing something..

Comment: Do you mean `yourObject.Price / 2` and `yourObject.DM / 2`?

Comment: dear I know , but what if i have 100 member

Comment: or even more members . should i have to make hard coded all of those :( .

Comment: are you iterating all members using `ng-repeat` or something like that? If yes, please share your code

Comment: You can check if is number  value is float? by using this
`function isFloat(n){
    return n === Number(n) && n % 1 !== 0;
}`

then if its true then devide it with 2.

Comment: question is clear , I have a object and as far i know we can't `ng-repeat` over object alone , for `ng-repeat` object should be in array

Comment: @AmitRamoliya but for that i've to loop over object members ! how can i loop over it

Comment: For looping Use this:

`for (var key in obj) {
    yourValue = obj[key];
}`

Comment: I don't think your question is that clear, in your example you have asked to divide all of the floating point numbers. All numbers in JavaScript are always 64-bit Floating point and it does not have a concept of Integers, shorts etc [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp). In your example the values 26.0 and 2.0 are counted as integers. So you should change at least one to reflect the need to only pickup numbers with real floating point values such as 26.01.

Comment: @Nabster have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/35063123/3728916

Comment: @ImranNaqvi I've seen that post and the core answer (excluding the please note section) is good. The JavaScript Number.isInteger(26.0) returns true and Number.isInteger(26.01) returns false. So I think you need to refine your question as all three numbers in your example are rightfully counted as integers. Hence my response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse through the object and check for float values. Then divide:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
    var n = obj[prop];
    if(n === Number(n) && n % 1 !== 0) {
        obj[prop] = n / 2;
    }
}
```

Please note:

- The above will match `14.2` and NOT `14.0` or `14` of course.
- For floats **without decimal places** use `!isNaN(n)` instead of `n === Number(n) && n % 1 !== 0`. But this will also match the **integers**. (will match `14.2`, `14.0` and `14`)
- If you just want to match the **floats**, that printed out as floats then use: `!isNaN(n) && n.toString().indexOf('.')`. (will match `14.2`, `14.0` and NOT `14`)
- Of course you could traverse with `$.each(..)` also.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all fields of your object using `$.each` that is a jQuery method:

```
var obj = { id: 1, name: "Grain", Price: 26.0, DM: 2.0 };

$.each(obj, function(i, el) {
    var floatValue = parseFloat(el);

    if(i != "id" && !isNaN(floatValue) && floatValue % 1 !== 0) {
        console.log(floatValue);
    }
});
```

Replace `console.log` with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly go through this code:

```
var myObj = {id: 1, name: "Grain", Price: 26.0, DM: 2.0};
var NewObj = {};
for (var key in myObj ) { 
   var yourValue = myObj [key]; 
   if(isFloat(yourValue )){
    NewObj.push({key:(yourValue /2)});
   }else{
    NewObj.push({key:(yourValue)});
   }
}

function isFloat(n){
 return n === Number(n) && n % 1 !== 0;
 }
```

Then finally Your **newObj** having result as per your thinking....

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `for` loop to iterate of the array.
2. Use the `===` operator to check if the object is of type `'number'`
3. Use `%1 == 0` to check if the number is a float or an integer.
4. Divide float by 2

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an array with the keys for the properties with the float values, like this

```
floatKeys = ['Price', 'DM'];
```

and iterate over the possible array and the keys.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, name: "Grain", Price: 26.0, DM: 2.0 }],
    floatKeys = ['Price', 'DM'];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    floatKeys.forEach(function (k) {
        a[k] /= 2;
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is your friend:

```
var obj = {id: 1, name: "Grain", Price: 26.0, DM: 2.0}
$.each(obj, function (key, value) {
    if ($.isNumeric(value) && !Number.isInteger(value)) {
        obj[key] /= 2;
    }
});
```

would interpret Price: "34.2" as a float also, though..